# How do I get proportions of the sock in my logo right?

Tags: logo, shapes

I am working on a logo for a sock business.

My current result is:

[image: This]

As you may notice the proportions of the abstracted sock are quite awful. Do you have an idea what I could do to make this better?

PS: If there are other recommendations don't be shy :)

Comment: Make it look more discernibly like a sock...? I see two rectangles.

Comment: Okay I will try this. Do you have some more hints?

Comment: You must become the sock in order to draw the sock! ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a quick 'Google' of socks (and a slightly irrational love of them) I noticed a couple of things that might help you.

-Unless there is a fold in the top of the sock (the part above the ankle) the width of this section tends to be less than the length.

-The heel and toes of a sock tends to be a bit of extra material making this part stick out so it might help to change the angle a little between both sections of the sock. Otherwise you could put the heel of the sock in, in either a different colour or a darker version of the colour you are using. I suggest that if you do this, a smooth curve would look great, it would be a nod in the direction of flat design. Though that is completely up to preference.

[image: This is a quick example of what I am talking about, though it might have been better to make the foot section a little narrower.]

Hope this helps; when I think socks I think heels and toes :)

Good luck!

Comment: Hey, I love your idea using another color for the between sections! Also good point with the proportions :)

Comment: Glad you like it :) the foot part in my example could be a little narrower but I thought it got the point across. Good luck with the project :)

Answer (score 3):

I tried to combine [JennaDesign's Idea](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/24971/16419) with your original approach. I think a striking heel shape can be enough and there should be as little colors as possible. Here is my sketch:

[image: my socksters logo approach]

Comment: Upvoted! That definitely looks good :)